# .conf changes have no effect on reboot in WSL?

Tags: configuration

I've tried making some changes in various .conf files in my Ubuntu WSL2 install, such as editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` with nano, adding `vm.max_map_count=262144` at the end of it, saving, then rebooting Windows, and finally checking if `vm.max_map_count` still `= 262144` ...

When I do a `sysctl vm.max_map_count` it still ends up showing the default `65530`.

However, if I do a `cat /etc/sysctl.conf` I'm still seeing that new line that I added to it, with `262144`?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. That doesn't work because `/etc/sysctl.conf` is not read when WSL2 starts up.

There's a workaround for that:
https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks

Answer (score 0):

This **github** issue appears to be the same **problem** and has just been elevated to a **feature**:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4232